# Finding combinations of values within multiple arrays that equal a given sum

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

If I have 5 different arrays, each containing five numerical values, and I need to find all possible combinations of values (taking one from each array) that add to a given sum, what would be the python code to achieve this?

Comment: this is a very hard problem for someone who is brand new to programming and python ... maybe this is a bad choice for a problem for you to solve at this point in your learning ... start smaller

Comment: @JoranBeasley thank you, I was just trying to simplify a problem that I saw and I thought it could be an interesting challenge as I learn more about Python.

Comment: i answered the question but its not how you would solve it for a programming competition or anytime the lists could get quite large ... but it should give you all the solutions (eventually)

Answer (score 0):

there are much better ways to solve this problem but here is how you can solve it by exploring the product of all 5 lists

```
import itertools
for potential_solution in itertools.product(list1,list2,list3,list4,list5):
    if sum(potential_solution) == targetValue:
       print(f"Solution {potential_solution} == {targetValue}")
```

that is likely the simplest solution to this problem... but it DOES NOT scale well

- if each list has 5 elements that 5**5 possible combinations (3125)
- if each list has 6 elements that 6**5 possible combinations (7776) more than 2x the number with 5 elements
- if each list has 7 elements that 7**5 possible combinations (16807) more than 2x the number with 6 elements
- by the time you are up to 10 elements there are 100k combinations to check